# How to cancel the prefixes only?

Tags: siunitx, cancel

See my MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{siunitx,
            cancel}

\begin{document}

  Test $\qty{1}{\cancel\mega\W}\cdot\SI{1}{\cancel\micro\ohm}$ test.

\end{document}
```

It is possible to cancel only the prefixes? In the MWE it would be `\mega` against `\micro`.

Thank you for your help and effort in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure what the meaning would be, but…

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx,cancel}

\DeclareSIPrefix{\cmega}{\cancel{\text{M}}}{6}
\DeclareSIPrefix{\cmicro}{\cancel{\text{\textmu}}}{-6}

\begin{document}

Test $\qty{1}{\cmega\W}\cdot\SI{1}{\cmicro\ohm}$ test.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hello @egreg! Sorry for the bad explanation, but you did the right thing! Thank you and @Al-Motasem Aldaoudeyeh too!

Comment: @Su-47 I'd avoid such notation; it can raise more doubts than it solves.

Comment: Hello @egreg! I'am very thankfull if you can edit my question, to make it more understandable, which is helpfull for all!

Answer (score 4):

[image]

You need to define a unit with no output `\DeclareSIUnit{\nounit}{\kern 0pt}` and put it after `\mega` and `\micro`

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{siunitx,
    cancel}

\DeclareSIUnit{\nounit}{\kern 0pt}

\begin{document}
    
    Test $\qty{1}{\cancel\mega\nounit\W}\cdot\SI{1}{\cancel\micro\nounit\ohm}$ test.
    
\end{document}
```